# tiling a pattern for beamer background

Tags: beamer, graphics, backgrounds

Is there a solution to have a given pattern (lets say as a `.png`file) **tiled** on the background (`background` or `background canvas`) for `beamer-presentations`?
I only find links to the `wallpaper` package, what seems to bring up many problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply define a new canvas background:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multido}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
 \parbox{\paperwidth}{%
   \multido{\iR=1+1}{10}{\multido{\iC=1+1}{13}{%
      \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{tiger}}\\}}}
\setbeamercolor{title page}{fg=blue}
\setbeamerfont{title page}{series=\bfseries,
  size=\Huge}

\begin{document}
\title{Hintergrundbild}
\author{Herbert Vo\ss}
\begin{frame}[plain]\maketitle\end{frame}

\frame{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Maybe my questions was not detailed enough: I'd like to put a pattern on the background which would be repeated (tiled) over all the page to fill it.

Comment: you can repeat the single pattern, see edited answer

Comment: Thanks for this simple idea. Maybe using \pgfdeclareimage and \pgfuseimage would make this even better?

Comment: if I am right then the image is included only once in the pdf. The reason why `\pgfdeclareimage` should make no difference.

Comment: Oh, this is new to me. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Hi there, I try to use this great snippet, but it seems, that the graphics leave a small margin at the top of each row. Thus, there are 9 horizontal lines in the background of the page. does this occur to you as well and do you know how to handle that? Thanks a lot beforehand